# Virtual areas and links generated by MVC's helper methods

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I'm trying to organize an MVC web application so that when the user browses to the root of the website, the login form is being shown.

Once the user successfully logs in, a dropdown is shown allowing the user to select in which "Project" they want to work in.

For example, the user selects "My Project" (ID: 100) and after submitting the choice, the browser is redirected to `http://website/100/Home/Index`

I later be using filters to see if the logged in user has access to project `100`

I managed to get this working with those routes:

```
//what happens when someone requests the root, /
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "LoginPage",
    url: "",
    defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login" }
);

//What happens when some browses to /projectid (ie: http://website/100)
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "HomePage",
    url: "{projectid}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);

//What happens when a client requests http://website/100/mystuff
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "AllDefault",
    url: "{projectid}/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "{*.*}", action = "Index" }
);

//What happens when a client requests an explicit controller/method (ex: http://site/100/mystuff/showit)
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "All",
    url: "{projectid}/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "{*.*}", action = "{*.*}" }
);
```

I see that `Html.ActionLink` properly appends the controller and method name after the project ID (100).

All links generated in `_Layout.cshtml` using `Html.ActionLink` are properly linking to `<selected project id>/controller/method`

The issue, is that sometimes in the views or even in the layout, some controllers and their methods have nothing to do with `projects` per se. They are sections of the website pertaining to general configurations and such.

Is there a way to create an override for `Html.ActionLink` to control its default behaviour ?

Also, if you roughly see what I'm trying to do and have better suggestions, shoot. :P